# Formatar valores de um array em outro

Tags: php, array

Tenho um CSV que me retorna o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ANO
            [1] => Sciences
            [2] => Mechanics
            [3] => Telecom
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2001
            [1] => 226
            [2] => 27
            [3] => 81
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2002
            [1] => 433
            [2] => 59
            [3] => 162
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2003
            [1] => 816
            [2] => 165
            [3] => 647
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2004
            [1] => 1098
            [2] => 421
            [3] => 864
        )

)
```

O que preciso transformar esse array em um json com o seguinte formato:

```
"categories": [
  {
    "category": [{"label": "2001"}, {"label": "2002"}, {"label": "2003"}, {"label": "2004"}]
  }
],
"dataset": [
  {
    "seriesname": "Sciences",
    "data": [{"value": "226"}, {"value": "433"}, {"value": "816"}, {"value": "1098"}]
  }, 
  {
    "seriesname": "Mechanics",
    "data": [{"value": "27"}, {"value": "59"}, {"value": "165"}, {"value": "421"}]
  }, 
  {
    "seriesname": "Telecom",
    "data": [{"value": "81"}, {"value": "162"}, {"value": "647"}, {"value": "864"}]
  }
]
```

To quebrando a minha cabeça nisso, mesmo sabendo que não é algo tão complexo, mas to emperrado mesmo =/

#### EDIT 1

Segue o que estou fazendo:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($spreadsheet_data); $i++) {

        $chart['categories']['category'][]['label'] = array_shift($spreadsheet_data[$i]);

        for ($d=0; $d < count($spreadsheet_data[$i]); $d++) {
            $chart['dataset']['data'][]['value'] = $spreadsheet_data[$i][$d];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Posta parte do seu código, assim podemos sugerir mudanças, para resolver o problema.

Comment: Adicionei o loop onde trato o array

Comment: Não dá para fazer exatamente o que vc quer não tem definir várias chaves com o mesmo nome por exemplo `label` e `value` teria que ser uma chava númerica nesse caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para se obter o array desejado, dado o array inicial, um dos primeiros passos seria fazer, o que em linguagem matemática chamamos de `transposição da matriz`

> Dada uma matriz A do tipo m x n, chama-se transposta de A e indica-se
>   por A^t a matriz que se obtém trocando-se ordenadamente as linhas pelas
>   colunas de A. A operação de obtenção de uma matriz transposta de A é
>   denominada transposição da matriz. [[2](http://www.infoescola.com/matematica/operacoes-com-matrizes-1/)]

Exp:

```
A = [ [A, B, C, D],
      [E, F, G, H],
      [I, J, L, M] ]

A^t = [ [A, E, I],
        [B, F, J],
        [C, G, L],
        [D, H, M] ]
```

E em PHP ela pode ser obtida da seguinte maneira:

```
$array = json_decode('[["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"],["I","J","L","M"]]');
// input => [["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"],["I","J","L","M"]]

$array = transpor_matriz($array);

echo json_encode($array);
// output => [["A","E","I"],["B","F","J"],["C","G","L"],["D","H","M"]]

function transpor_matriz($array) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($array as  $rowkey => $row) {
        foreach($row as $colkey => $col){
            $out[$colkey][$rowkey]=$col;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

**Input** x **Output** [[3](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)]:

[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O resto do algorítimo **EU** implementaria assim:

```
$array = json_decode('[["ANO","Sciences","Mechanics","Telecom"],[2001,226,27,81],[2002,433,59,162],[2003,816,165,647],[2004,1098,421,864]]');
// Input => [["ANO","Sciences","Mechanics","Telecom"],[2001,226,27,81],[2002,433,59,162],[2003,816,165,647],[2004,1098,421,864]]
$array = transpor_matriz($array);
// Apos a transposição => [["ANO",2001,2002,2003,2004],["Sciences",226,433,816,1098],["Mechanics",27,59,165,421],["Telecom",81,162,647,864]]

$categories = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++){
    if($i != 0){
        $categories["category"]["label".$i] = $array[0][$i];
    }
}
// Não preciso mais da primeira linha de anos, então apago ela
unset($array[0]);
$array = array_filter($array);

$dataset = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as  $rowkey => $inner) {
    $j = 0;
    foreach($inner as $colkey => $col){
        if($j == 0){
            $dataset[$i]["seriesname"] = $col;
        }else{
            $dataset[$i]["data"][$j]["value"] = $col;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
// Output terá dois arrays, categorias e dados
$output = array(array("categories" => $categories),array("dataset" => $dataset));
echo json_encode($output);
// Output => [{"categories":{"category":{"label1":2001,"label2":2002,"label3":2003,"label4":2004}}},{"dataset":[{"seriesname":"Sciences","data":{"1":{"value":226},"2":{"value":433},"3":{"value":816},"4":{"value":1098}}},{"seriesname":"Mechanics","data":{"1":{"value":27},"2":{"value":59},"3":{"value":165},"4":{"value":421}}},{"seriesname":"Telecom","data":{"1":{"value":81},"2":{"value":162},"3":{"value":647},"4":{"value":864}}}]}]

function transpor_matriz($array) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($array as  $rowkey => $row) {
        foreach($row as $colkey => $col){
            $out[$colkey][$rowkey]=$col;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Desse modo temos o seguinte **Input** x **Output**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

*[obs]:* Como o @rray [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191390/formatar-valores-de-um-array-em-outro#comment395162_191390) temos que manter uma chave numérica, se não o dado simplesmente poderia ser sobreposto. Veja os exemplos:

## 1

```
$teste["oi"] = 5;
$teste["oi"] = 10;
echo json_encode($teste);
// talvez seja esse output "esperado" = {"oi"{5,10}}
// output obtida = {"oi":10}
```

## 2

```
$teste["oi"][0] = 5;
$teste["oi"][1] = 10;
echo json_encode($teste);
// output esperada = {"oi"{5,10}}
// output obtida = {"oi":[5,10]}
```

Desse modo o resultado obtido não foi exatamente idêntico ao esperado, mas bem próximo